# why does my code work for some test cases but not others

Tags: c

I was asked to translate this algorithm into code

```
//compute the max of size1 and (x_offset + size2).  Call this w

//compute the max of size1 and (y_offset + size2).  Call this h

//count from 0 to h. Call the number you count with y

//count from 0 to w. Call the number you count with x

  //check if  EITHER
  //    ((x is between x_offset  and x_offset +size2) AND 
  //     y is equal to either y_offset OR y_offset + size2 - 1 )
  //  OR
  //    ((y is between y_offset and y_offset + size2) AND
  //     x is equal to either x_offset OR x_offset + size2 -1)
  // if so, print a *

  //if not,
  // check if EITHER
  //    x is less than size1 AND (y is either 0 or size1-1)
  // OR
  //    y is less than size1 AND (x is either 0 or size1-1)
  //if so, print a #

  //else print a space
//when you finish counting x from 0 to w, 
//print a newline
```

and here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void squares(int size1, int x_offset, int y_offset, int size2) {
  int w = (size1 > x_offset + size2) ? size1 : x_offset + size2;
  int h = (size1 > y_offset + size2) ? size1 : y_offset + size2;
  for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
      if (((x >= x_offset && x < x_offset + size2) &&
           (x == y_offset || x == y_offset + size2 - 1)) ||
          ((y >= y_offset && y < y_offset + size2) &&
           (x == x_offset || x == x_offset + size2 - 1))) {
        printf("*");
      } else if ((x < size1 && (y == 0 || y == size1 - 1)) ||
                 (y < size1 && (x == 0 || x == size1 - 1))) {
        printf("#");
      } else {
        printf(" ");
      }
    }
printf("\n");
    }
}
```

However, my code only works for some test cases
e.g.

```
Testing ./squares 1 0 0 1
PASSED
 - Correct
Testing ./squares 1 0 0 5
Your program produced the wrong output!
 - Incorrect
Testing ./squares 1 0 0 9
Your program produced the wrong output!
 - Incorrect
Testing ./squares 1 0 1 1
PASSED
 - Correct
Testing ./squares 1 0 1 5
Your program produced the wrong output!
 - Incorrect
Testing ./squares 1 0 1 9
Your program produced the wrong output!
 - Incorrect
Testing ./squares 1 0 3 1
PASSED
 - Correct
Testing ./squares 1 0 3 5
Your program produced the wrong output!
 - Incorrect
Testing ./squares 1 0 3 9
Your program produced the wrong output!
 - Incorrect
Testing ./squares 1 0 8 1
PASSED
 - Correct
```

Could anyone help me with this? Thank you so so much!

Comment: Is *between* exclusive or inclusive?

Comment: "between" implies to me using `>=, <=` or `>, <`, and not `>=, <` like this code does.

Comment: `x == y_offset` is certainly amiss.

Comment: Thanks so much.I have already fixed the code

Comment: counting `y` from `0` to `w` means to me `for(y = 0; y <= w; y++)` and not as written in the code (`for(y = 0; y < w; y++)`).

Answer (score 1):

Consider coding to a contract in a way that is easier to follow.

Given

> //check if  EITHER
>     //    ((x is between x_offset  and x_offset +size2) AND
>     //     y is equal to either y_offset OR y_offset + size2 - 1 )
>     //  OR
>     //    ((y is between y_offset and y_offset + size2) AND
>     //     x is equal to either x_offset OR x_offset + size2 -1)
>     // if so, print a *

What if code was instead of

```
  if (((x >= x_offset && x < x_offset + size2) &&
       (x == y_offset || x == y_offset + size2 - 1)) ||
      ((y >= y_offset && y < y_offset + size2) &&
       (x == x_offset || x == x_offset + size2 - 1))) {
    printf("*");
```

was

```
  if (is_between(x, x_offset, x_offset + size2) && 
      is_either2(x, y_offset, y_offset + size2 - 1)) ||
      is_between(y, y_offset, y_offset + size2) && 
      is_either2(x, x_offset, x_offset + size2 - 1))) {
    printf("*");
```

It maybe easier to see the mistake

```
// y is equal to either y_offset OR y_offset + size2 - 1 )  
//         v
is_either2(x, y_offset, y_offset + size2 - 1)
```

---

Also it helps deal with contract ambiguities of inclusive or exclusive endpoints in the idea of *in between* as we only need to amend/update the function/macro `in_between()` [@Shawn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51336773/why-does-my-code-work-for-some-test-cases-but-not-others#comment89648319_51336773).

Using the non-symmetric `>=, <` for *in between* is suspicious.

Comment: Thank so much, I will double check the in between

Answer (score 0):

check condition in `if` statement.

`y is equal to either y_offset OR y_offset + size2 - 1` is `y == y_offset || y == y_offset + size2 - 1`

change `(x == y_offset || x == y_offset + size2 - 1))` to `(y == y_offset || y == y_offset + size2 - 1))` in second line of `if`

```
if (((x >= x_offset && x < x_offset + size2) && // (x is between x_offset  and x_offset +size2)
     (y == y_offset || y == y_offset + size2 - 1)) // y is equal to either y_offset OR y_offset + size2 - 1
     ||
     ((y >= y_offset && y < y_offset + size2) && //(y is between y_offset and y_offset + size2)
     (x == x_offset || x == x_offset + size2 - 1))) // x is equal to either x_offset OR x_offset + size2 -1
{
}
```